# Electrical Engineering (complex numbers)

Tags: complex-numbers

Electrical Engineering ($j=i=\sqrt{-1}$):

$$H_v(\omega)=\frac{R}{R+\frac{1}{j\omega C}}=\frac{j\omega CR}{1+Rj\omega C}$$

And we know that: $\omega_0=\frac{1}{RC}\Longleftrightarrow RC=\frac{1}{\omega_0}$

So we got:

$$H_v(\omega)=\frac{j\frac{\omega} {\omega_0}}{1+j\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}}$$

And my book say that I can write:

$$H_v(\omega)=\frac{j\frac{\omega} {\omega_0}}{1+j\frac{\omega} {\omega_0}}=\frac{1}{1-j\frac{\omega_0} {\omega}}$$

But I don’t see why, can someone help me?

Comment: Mulitply the numerator and the denominator by $-j\frac{\omega_0}{\omega}$ and remember that $j\times\left(-j\right)=1$.

Comment: Thnxx, that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$H_v(\omega)=\frac{R}{R+\frac{1}{j\omega C}}=\frac{j\omega CR}{1+Rj\omega C}=$$
$$\frac{j\omega(RC)}{1+j\omega(RC)}=\frac{j\omega \frac{1}{\omega_0}}{1+j\frac{1}{\omega_0}}=$$
$$\frac{j\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}}{1+j\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}}=\frac{\frac{ j\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}}{ j\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}}}{\frac{1+j\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}}{ j\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}}}=$$

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{ j\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{ \frac{j\omega}{\omega_0}}}=$$

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{\omega_0}{j\omega}}=\frac{1}{1+-j\frac{\omega_0}{\omega}}=\frac{1}{1-j\frac{\omega_0}{\omega}}$$

Comment: I'm going to check this answer!

Comment: You're welcome,  Buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Whan you use the iverse of $j$ remeber that:
$$
\dfrac{1}{j}=-j
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply top and bottom by $j\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}$ and use the fact that $j^2=-1$.

Comment: @Vlad Yes it does provide an answer to the question.